# Merging ArXiv paper and conference paper on Google Scholar

Tags: publications, citations, arxiv, google-scholar

In my Google Scholar profile, I have a paper which I uploaded to ArXiv a while ago, which has a few citations. Since then, that same paper has been accepted for a peer-reviewed conference. It was only uploaded to ArXiv to bridge the gap between the paper submission date, and the release of the official conference paper after the conference.

How can I merge citations for my ArXiv paper and my conference paper, such that there is only one entry in my Google Scholar profile, where that entry is listed as the conference paper rather than the ArXiv paper?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

"My citations", then tick the square boxes next to the papers you want to merge, then click on the "merge" button that just appeared.

Comment: Will this option keep the citations count for two papers after the merger?

Comment: Yes, citations should be preserved. The operation is reversible anyway, so you can try.