# Google Scholar has indexed the arXiv version and publisher version of my paper - but lists arXiv over the publisher. How to fix this?

Tags: citations, google-scholar, bibliometrics

I published a paper in *Nature*. (Not really, but just an example.) I put the preprint of the article up on arXiv. Now on Google Scholar it shows:

```
A definitive proof that P=NP when N=1 
R Dodecahedron
arXiv preprint arXiv:3141.59265 12  2017
```

When I click the article, it says "`Cited by 20    Related articles    All 6 versions`". When I click `All 6 versions`, the *Nature* bibliographic information is listed there. How do I get that to be listed as default, instead of the preprint version, on my Scholar profile? As the article was published two years ago, I do not think the problem will fix itself at this point.

Comment: Does the arxiv entry contain the link to the published version?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not 100% sure this will work (since I don't really have a way to test it), but I think you can try this. On your Google Scholar page (signed in):

1. Click on the link to the article in question --> this should pop up a window with more details.
2. Click on the "edit" symbol (pencil).
3. At the bottom, select "Unmerge this article and add it to my profile as a separate entry." --> close the window.
4. Select the two (or more) versions of the article and select merge.
5. This should pop up a window asking you to "Select the best version of the article." --> choose the *Nature* version.

The answers to these related questions may also be helpful: [merging](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/62195/merging-arxiv-paper-and-conference-paper-on-google-scholar?rq=1), [linking](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/79845/link-ieee-xplore-article-with-its-arxiv-version-in-google-scholar?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks. That worked for fixing my profile. Unfortunately, when someone just searches for the article, it still comes up with the preprint version, and its publication information is masked until they go to `All 6 versions.` Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: Ahh I see. Hmm, no I don’t know. That’s annoying. Maybe the change on your profile just takes time to propagate to the rest of google scholar?